# Each child should have a unique key prop even they're set - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm getting my navbar routes from a json file like this:

```
{
  "categorias": [
    {
      "nombre": "Faltas de profesorado",
      "componentes": [
        {
          "type": "url",
          "icon": "fas fa-plus",
          "title": "Nueva falta",
          "url": "/"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "icon": "fas fa-comment",
          "title": "Gestionar faltas",
          "url": "/"
        },{
              "type": "desplegable",
              "title": "Reservar un moscoso",
              "url": "/",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "url",
                  "title": "Moscoso de urgencia",
                  "url": "/"
                }

              ]
            }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I map them in my component.

I tried changing all keys to nanoid(6) to get random strings. Still no success.

```
const NavRoutes = ({rutas}) => (
  /* Mapeo de rutas */
  rutas.map(ruta => (<div className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__wrapper} key={nanoid(6)}>
    <div open={true} className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__name__container} onClick={(e) => e.currentTarget.toggleAttribute('open')}>
      <i className={`${styles.icon} fas fa-arrow-right`}/>
      <h5 className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__name}>{ruta.nombre}</h5>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__container}>
    {
      (ruta.componentes?.length > 0)?
      ruta.componentes.map((subRuta,i) => (
        <ul key={nanoid(6)} className={styles.NavigationBar__route__list}>
          <li key={nanoid(6)}>
            <i className={`${styles.icon} ${subRuta.icon}`}/>
            <Link to={`${subRuta.url}`}>{subRuta.title}</Link>
          </li>
        {
          (subRuta.items?.length > 0 && subRuta.type === 'desplegable')
          ?
          <ul key={nanoid(6)}>
          {subRuta.items.map((item,i) => (<>
            <li key={nanoid(6)}>
              <Link to={`${item.url}`}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
            {(item.items?.length > 0)
              ?
              item.items.map(extra => (
                <ul key={nanoid(6)}>
                  <li><Link to={`${item.url}`}>{extra.title}</Link></li>
                </ul>
                ))
              :
              ''
            }
          </>))}
          </ul>
          :
          ''
        }
        </ul>
        )
      )
      :
      'Vacio'
    }
    </div>
  </div>))
  /* Fin mapeo de rutas */
)
```

And mapping them in my NavBar component.

Everything works but in my console appears the error, even though I have alerady defined a key after each mapped element (no elements have the same key):

> ````
> should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `NavRoutes`. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
>     at NavRoutes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:544:5)
>     at div
>     at div
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33611:5
>     at nav
>     at NavBar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:675:69)
>     at div
>     at Home
>     at Index (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1826:66)
>     at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64433:5)
>     at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64366:15)
>     at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63842:5)
>     at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1434:5)
>     at App ```
> ````

Can someone take a look? I've tried many things none work.

## FIXED

The error was here, the fragment had no key.

```
subRuta.items.map((item,i) => (<>
            <li key={nanoid(6)}>
              <Link to={`${item.url}`}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
            {(item.items?.length > 0)
              ?
              item.items.map(extra => (
                <ul key={nanoid(6)}>
                  <li><Link to={`${item.url}`}>{extra.title}</Link></li>
                </ul>
                ))
              :
              ''
            }
          </>))
```

Changed the fragment to a ul. Thank you all.

```
subRuta.items.map((item,i) => (<ul key={nanoid(6)}>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${item.url}`}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
            {(item.items?.length > 0)
              ?
              item.items.map(extra => (
                <ul key={nanoid(6)}>
                  <li><Link to={`${item.url}`}>{extra.title}</Link></li>
                </ul>
                ))
              :
              ''
            }
          </ul>))
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are two (or more) instances of `ruta` that has the same `nombre`?

Comment: No. All of them have different names.

Comment: @ask4you - look at the first map. You have 2 divs with the value `key={'${ruta.nombre}-container'}` - why? you don't need a key on every div, just the first in a loop.

Comment: @ask4you - read my update. you have way too many keys for no reason.

Comment: @gwalshington See edit. Changed al keys to `key={nanoid(6)}`, which return a random string. Still have the same warning.

Comment: @ask4you - i've updated my answer and posted here in comments -- you have too many unnecessary keys.

Comment: Well, After checking 20 questions with similar issues, your FIXED message finally helped me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @gwalsgington answer, you can use a random string generator like [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) to your project. Then you can use it like this after importing nanoid as `import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'`:

```
{subRuta.items.map(item => (<>
        <li key={nanoid(4)}>
          <Link to={`${item.url}`}>{item.title}</Link>
        </li>
        {(item.items?.length > 0)
          ?
          item.items.map(extra => (
            <ul key={nanoid(4)}>
              <li><Link to={`${item.url}`}>{extra.title}</Link></li>
            </ul>
            ))
          :
          ''
      }
```

Comment: Tried it, changed all my keys to `nanoid(6)`, still the same error.

Comment: Did you try it for all the keys in the code snippet you showed?

Comment: Yeah. See edit.

Comment: I think the react fragment here also needs a key:
```js
{subRuta.items.map((item,i) => (<>
            <li key={nanoid(6)}>
```

That is the empty tags <>

Comment: Try using `<React.Fragment key={nanoid(6)}> <React.Fragment>`
Or find a wayy to remove the fragment without affecting the structure of the list.

Comment: That worked! I didn't know a fragment would need a key. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to upvote.

However, your code structure might need some cleanup though.

keys that are not part of the outer JSX structure in a map can be discarded. That is, you can have the key on the React Fragment <> but remove it for every child tag adn all will still be good.

Comment: Pretty sure that is masking the issue that I brought up - there's a freaking key on every element. This is a hack, not solving what the issue actually was.

Comment: Sure I will. I knew keys had to be just in parents, but i wouldn't have figured out the fragment was the causing it!

Comment: @gwalshington Actually changing the fragment to another element and adding a key to it fixed the warning. Then removed all unnecesary keys. Thanks anyway to your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the key to the index, not the title. This way if you have duplicate titles, it won't have a duplicate key.

```
     {subRuta.items.map((item, index) => (<>
        <li key={index}>
          <Link to={`${item.url}`}>{item.title}</Link>
        </li>
        {(item.items?.length > 0)
          ?
          item.items.map((extra, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>
              <li><Link to={`${item.url}`}>{extra.title}</Link></li>
            </ul>
            ))
          :
          ''
      }
```

Additionally, you're giving keys to wayyyy too many divs. Look at the first map - there's a key on every div. Remove all that. You only need a key on the first div of a loop.

There are 3 keys in this one section, and 2 are exactly the same `key={'${ruta.nombre}-container'}`. The only key you need is the first one.

```
   <div className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__wrapper} key={ruta.nombre}>
    <div key={`${ruta.nombre}-container`} open={true} className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__name__container} onClick={(e) => e.currentTarget.toggleAttribute('open')}>
      <i className={`${styles.icon} fas fa-arrow-right`}/>
      <h5 className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__name}>{ruta.nombre}</h5>
    </div>
    <div key={`${ruta.nombre}-list-container`} className={styles.NavigationBar__routes__container}>
```

Comment: There are plenty of articles, why is using index as key in react considered bad practice. [example](https://dev.to/shiv1998/why-not-to-use-index-as-key-in-react-lists-practical-example-3e66). Best solution would be to define some unique id in json itself.

Comment: Tried it. Both with `<li key={index}>` or `<li key={'${item.title}-${index}'}>`. Still the same error.

Comment: Simply give each key a unique prefix and then you a good to use index. Something like `´parent_${index}´` then `´child_${index}´` etc

Comment: @ask4you - make sure ALL keys are updated. That's 100% the issue - you have a lot of keys in that code, I was just giving an example of how to write the function with a key.

Comment: @Wraithy - thanks for the info! I'll read that. But ultimately, the issue for this question is they are using a title, and there must be duplicate titles. They need a unique identifier for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding random key to react fragment helped me aswell. Import **{nanoid}** from 'nanoid' and pass it to the key in fragment
**(<React.Fragment key={nanoid(6)}/>)**